# Probability of branching times under a Ornstein–Uhlenbeck-Yule process

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, stochastic-processes

According to Edwards, 1970 the probability density of the branching times in a Brownian-Yule branching process can be expressed as:

\begin{equation}
P(\mathbf{u'},n|\lambda,n_0,T)=\lambda^{n-n_0}\frac{(n - 1)!}{(n_0 - 1)!}\exp\left[-\lambda(nT + \sum_{i=n_0}^{n-1}u_i')\right]
\end{equation}

where $\lambda$ is the birth (branching) rate, $n$ is the number of particles at present time, $T$ is the time of the first branching event (backwards in time), $n_0$ is the number of branches at a given time after the first branching event, and $u_i'$ correspond to the branching time.

This probability distribution is then divided by the probability that the branching process produce exactly $n$ particles in time $T$ under a pure birth process:

\begin{equation}
P(n|\lambda,n_0,T)=\binom{n -1}{n-n_0}\exp(-\lambda Tn_0)[1-\exp(-\lambda T)]^{n-n_0}
\end{equation}

Then, the probability of the branching times under the Yule process is:

\begin{equation}
P(\mathbf{u'}|\lambda,n_0,T,n)\propto\frac{P(\mathbf{u'},n|\lambda,n_0,T)}{P(n|\lambda,n_0,T)}={(n - n_0)!}\left(\frac{\lambda\exp(-\lambda T)}{1-\exp(-\lambda T)}\right)^{n-n_0} \exp\left(-\lambda\sum_{i=n_0}^{n-1}u_i' \right)
\end{equation}

Now, I am currently interested in identifying the same probability density distribution in the case of a Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process. That is, the probability of the branching times under a Ornstein–Uhlenbeck-Yule process. Any suggestion or reference?

Edwards, 1970. Estimation of the Branch Points of a Branching Diffusion Process. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society B, 32(2):155– 164.